# Modify value of specific attributes in XML file dynamically

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to modify all the attribute values of `Uri` in `edmx:Reference` of XML file.

My file(`Chassis.xml`) contents are

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
  <edmx:Reference Uri="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/csd01/complete/vocabularies/Org.OData.Measures.V1.xml">
    <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Measures.V1" Alias="Measures"/>
  </edmx:Reference>
  <edmx:Reference Uri="http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/RedfishExtensions_v1.xml">
    <edmx:Include Namespace="RedfishExtensions.v1_0_0" Alias="Redfish"/>
    <edmx:Include Namespace="Validation.v1_0_0" Alias="Validation"/>
  </edmx:Reference>
  <edmx:Reference Uri="http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/Resource_v1.xml">
    <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource"/>
    <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_0"/>
    <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_1_0"/>
  </edmx:Reference>
  <edmx:Reference Uri="http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/Thermal_v1.xml">
    <edmx:Include Namespace="Thermal"/>
  </edmx:Reference>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

I am able to read all the values of `Uri` but cannot update the values dynamically to same file.The code used for getting the value of `Uri` is

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Chassis.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.findall('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx}Reference'):
    if 'Uri' in item.attrib:
        item.attrib['Uri']="new-uri"
ET.write("Chassis.xml")
```

My question how to read and modify attribute values of `Uri` dynamically to same file?

Comment: You need to show the Python code that you have been working with.

Comment: @Tomalak Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Here we define the register namespaces and this code can change the Uri of Reference:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Chassis_v1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.findall('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx}Reference'):
    if 'Uri' in item.attrib:
    a=item.attrib['Uri']
        b=a.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
        item.attrib['Uri']="/redfish/v1/schemas/"+b

ET.register_namespace('edmx','http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx')
ET.register_namespace('','http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm')
tree.write("Chassis_v1.xml",xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8',method="xml")
```